# Connecting to MS SQL Server 2000 using PHP with Windows Credentials

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I know this is not a new question because i found lots of similar questions but not the one which solves my issue.

Well my question is ***how do i connect to a remote sql 2000 server using other domain windows credentials (not the one im logged in with) with php running on apache (xampp)***... and the server doesnt run named instance.

These the things i tried,

1. installed SQL Native client for my php 5.3
2. got the .dll files to the ext folder
3. made sure i got the sqlsrv up and running via phpinfo
4. mssql.secureconnections is on
5. edited the php.ini and restart the apache server

So, i tried looking at various posts here and elsewhere but couldnt actually solve my problem.

i tried several codes, but here is the one which im currently trying with

> $server = "XXX_Server";
>
> $connInfo = array( "Database"=>"DB_Server", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");
>
> $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connInfo);
>
> if( $conn )
>
> {
>   echo "Connection established.";
>
> }
>
> else
>
> {
>
> echo "Connection could not be established.";
>
> die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
>
> }

and i get error as shown below,

> Connection could not be established.
>
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xx\username'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xx\username'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xx\username'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'xx\username'. ) )

where xx = domain

And please note that , the client has given me a windows credentials which has access to the server and must use only this. And when i hardcoded my credentials (which has access too) in the script, it didnt work and got the error above, but when i use QueryExpress / SQL Studio, im able to access the db using windows credentials (mine).

So to make it simple, i need to write a script where i need to hardcode the windows credentials and connect to a SQL DB (Stuck here) and make the script accessible for only few using windows ad authentication (which i know how to do)

Please provide me some tips and advice as im stuck and dont know how to proceed. Whatever i research and try, i end up doing the same thing, facing a wall :P

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you connect with sql studio with the same username and password?

Comment: Well, i tried but when i select the windows authentication from the dropdown in SQL Studio, it automatically takes mine and im unable to enter the credentials which i want to... :(

Comment: @Krishna -> Try using "Run As" (Right-click the short-cut). The code you have is for database credentials, which as you found out, are a totally different beast than Windows Authentication. You might have to  ensure the web server runs under said credentials to get this to work.

Comment: Well when i try to run the SQL Studio with the credentials provided to me using the "Run As", i get an error saying unable to logon..Login Failure... Err this is a bit confusing and a bit annoying :| ... because the client changed the password while on call with me and he is SURE that the credentials work....  Help !